# How do I pass multiple parameters using history.push?

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-router-dom

In React I am trying to pass both pathname and another parameter using history.push.
When it executes the application redirects to the specified page but the state is undefined so I cannot obtain the other parameter.

```
<Route path='/main' exact component={Main}  />

import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
var history = useHistory();
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    history.push("/main", { state: 'test'});
};


const Main= (props) => {
    console.log(props.location.state);
};
export default Main;
```

In Main, props.location.state is undefined.  Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For getting location's state in functional component without route props or `withRoute` HOC, you would use `useLocation` instead:**

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Main= () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    console.log(location);
};
```

And to pass multiple variables through location state, use object:

```
history.push("/page1", { pathname: "test", anotherParam: "test2" });
```

*Note that: The second param of `history.push` is already the state, so you don't need to name it a `state`*

Live Example:

[image: Edit React Router - 404 - Navbar condition (forked)]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the object version of the push:

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  history.push({
    pathname: "/main",
    state: 'test',
  });
};
```

Please also ensure the receiving component is also receiving [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

```
const Main= (props) => {
  console.log(props.location.state);
};
```

If it not then ensure access to the `location` object via the `useLocation` hook or the `withRouter` Higher Order Component to have them injected as props.

Answer (score 0):

We can utilize this format too

```
 history.push({
  pathname: '/some-path',
  search: '?q=india&id=12345'
 })
```